# pipeline function return table "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: oracle, function, pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline function to return a table and I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  I've followed some examples and am getting inconsistent datatypes and I don't understand why.  I assume it has in someway the row is getting returned in way that mismatches the row definition.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

```
DROP TYPE ODSMaxVRSN_TBL;
DROP TYPE ODSMaxVRSN_ROW;


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ODSMAXVRSN_ROW AS OBJECT
(
  audit_sls_trans_key     Number
,sls_tran_key                 NUMBER
,sls_4_part_key           varchar2(50),
sls_audit_rvsn_nbr      NUMBER,
sls_tran_key_unaud      NUMBER
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ODSMaxVRSN_TBL AS TABLE OF ODSMaxVRSN_ROW
/

create or replace FUNCTION GET_ODSMAXVRSN (in_dtFmt varchar2,in_start_date varchar2,in_end_date varchar2)
         RETURN ODSMAXVRSN_TBL PIPELINED IS 

l_row ODSMAXVRSN_ROW;
l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR; 
l_sql    VARCHAR2(2000);

begin

    l_sql := 'With 
sales as (
select s.SLS_TRANS_KEY,s.SLS_4_PART_KEY, nvl(s.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR,0) sLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR, a.AUDIT_SLS_TRANS_KEY 
from SLS_TRANS s
left outer join AUDIT_SLS_TRaNs a 
        on s.SLS_4_PART_KEY = a.SLS_4_PART_KEY and a.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR = 1
    where s.REC_CRT_TS between to_date('''|| in_start_date ||''','''||in_dtFmt ||''') and to_date('''||in_end_date ||''','''||in_dtFmt||''')' ||' 
    and  a.AUDIT_SLS_TRANS_KEY > 0
        OR s.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR  > 0
)
, maxrvsn as (
Select trn.SLS_4_PART_KEY
    , to_number(max(SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR)) SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR
    from sales trn 
    group by trn.sls_4_part_key
)
, unaudited as (
select  t.SLS_TRANS_KEY, t.SLS_4_PART_KEY, t.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR
from SLS_TRANS  t
where t.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR is null
)
select t.AUDIT_SLS_TRANS_KEY
,t.SLS_TRANS_KEY
,t.SLS_4_PART_KEY
,t.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR
,u.sls_trans_key 
from sales t
inner join maxrvsn m on m.SLS_4_PART_KEY = t.SLS_4_PART_KEY and m.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR = t.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR
left outer join unaudited u on t.SLS_4_PART_KEY = u.SLS_4_PART_KEY';
SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_sql);
    OPEN l_cursor FOR l_sql;
    loop
        fetch l_cursor into l_row;
        exit when l_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        pipe row (l_row);

    end loop;
    CLOSE l_cursor;
    return;
end GET_ODSMaxVRSN;

select * from table(GET_ODSMAXVRSN('yyyy-mm-dd','2017-07-25','2017-07-31'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this one:

```
pipe row ( ODSMAXVRSN_ROW(
   l_row.AUDIT_SLS_TRANS_KEY,
   l_row.SLS_TRANS_KEY,
   l_row.SLS_4_PART_KEY,
   l_row.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR,
   l_row.sls_trans_key)       
);
```

For debugging insert

```
SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 
   l_row.AUDIT_SLS_TRANS_KEY ||','||
   l_row.SLS_TRANS_KEY||','||
   l_row.SLS_4_PART_KEY||','||
   l_row.SLS_AUDIT_RVSN_NBR||','||
   l_row.sls_trans_key);
```

In order to see whether all values have correct data type.

Better set input values as `DATE` datatype, not `VARCHAR2`, i.e.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_ODSMAXVRSN (
    in_start_date DATE,in_end_date DATE)
    RETURN ODSMAXVRSN_TBL PIPELINED IS 

...

    where s.REC_CRT_TS between :in_start_date and :in_end_date 

...

OPEN l_cursor FOR l_sql USING in_start_date, in_end_date;
```

or in case you have to insist on VARCHAR2, you also try

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_ODSMAXVRSN (
    in_dtFmt varchar2,in_start_date varchar2,in_end_date varchar2)
    RETURN ODSMAXVRSN_TBL PIPELINED IS 

...

    where s.REC_CRT_TS between :in_start_date and :in_end_date 

...

OPEN l_cursor FOR l_sql USING 
    TO_DATE(in_start_date, in_dtFmt), 
    TO_DATE(in_end_date, in_dtFmt);
```